# Pandas - getting an index of a row in a pandas apply function

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my pandas code:

```py
def calcObj(row):
    d = dict(calc1 = iferror(row.Hours1.sum(), row.Hours2.sum(), 0, '+'))
    
    if row.Process == 'A': # this doesn't work
        d['ProcessKey'] = 700
    else:
        d['ProcessKey'] = 500
    
    return pd.Series(d)

    
df.groupby(['MainProcess']).apply(calcObj)
```

I am trying to check if a process name is A and if it is return a different value.
Unfortunately it doesn't work and i get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Process '

I assume it's because i am not grouping by process only by MainProcess.

Is there any way to get access to this item within the apply function ? Any other work-around would also be very helful

Here is my example dataframe, BG/MainProcess, CoreProcess and Process1 are indexes, Hours1/Hours2 are columns :

```
Bg              MainProcess                CoreProcess          Process      Hours1      Hours2                                        
Building1       MainProcess-1              CoreProcess-1        S-Process-1     150         250
                                                                S-Process-2     150         250
                                           CoreProcess-2        S-Process-3     150         250
                                                                S-Process-1     150         250
                                                                S-Process-2     150         250
Building2       MainProcess-2              CoreProcess-3        S-Process-1     150         250
                                                                S-Process-2     150         250
                MainProcess-3              CoreProcess-4        S-Process-1     150         250
                                                                S-Process-2     150         250
                                                                S-Process-3     150         250
```

Comment: when you `groupby().apply()`, the in put `row` is actually the sub-frame with the same key, e.g. `MainProcess` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Beware, the columns in the index are not columns of the DataFrame!

In your example, as `Process` is in the (multi-) index, `df['Process']` will raise a `KeyError` **independently of the groupby**. You must *reset* the column from the index to be able to use it. For example you could reset it before the groupby:

```
df.reset_index(level='Process').groupby(['MainProcess']).apply(calcObj)
```

But **beware**: `calcObj` will not receive *rows* here but the sub-dataframes having same values in the `MainProcess` column...

Comment: thanks Serge - i followed your approach but now when i do```print(row.Process)``` it returns all Processes for eac iteration, not one of them attached to the row

Comment: @Pythiro: You failed to give the expected result and your code uses an `iferror` function that I do not know. To be honest, I could not understand what you were trying to do. So I could only focus on the *This does not work* line, and warn that `calcObj` is not applied row wise. If you want more help, you should at least give the expected result.